# How to remove div if it has not pure text?

Tags: jquery

How do I remove a div if it is like:

```
<div>...</div>
or
<div>"</div>
```

I know i can do:

```
$("div:empty").remove();
```

But that obviously isn't correct in this case as the div is not empty since it has dots or "

What I mean with pure text is:

```
<div>MY TEXT</div>
```

Basically any text but **dots** or **"**

Comment: You mean to say, if `div` has no children?

Comment: not really, i mean a div with no <div>Text example</div>

Comment: What do you mean by **pure text**?

Comment: @Azim question updated

Comment: Is a blank considered non-empty? So is `<div> </div>` considered "not pure text"?

Comment: blank is fine, .empty() will remove it. But with dots how do you handle it? or with " " like <div>""</div>. Those symbols are text too

Comment: why a down vote, i do not know.

Comment: @rob.m Works now for my answer. Can you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method like following. In `filter` replace all `"` and `.` with empty string and then if the string is empty return `true`.

```js
$('div').filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim().replace(/\"|\./g,'');
    return !text;
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Any text</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>"</div>
```

Comment: @Azim how can i add more symbols? A link to learn would be fine, thanks

Comment: You can use regex `or(|)` condition to add more symbols like if you want to add `#` then your regex will be `/\"|\.|#/g` @rob.m

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the `<div>` has any children, if not, you can remove it.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\.|"]+$/i);
if (pattern.test($(this).text().trim()))
  $(this).remove();
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").each(function () {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\.|"]+$/i);
    if (pattern.test($(this).text().trim()))
      $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>....</div>
<div>Has pure text Not Removed</div>
<div>Also the below are removed.</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>"</div>
```

Comment: <div>...</div> does it have children in this case?

Comment: i mean are the dots considered as children? because if so this isn't correct

Comment: @rob.m You mean to say, the opposite of this? Just make it into `!=`... `:)`

Comment: @rob.m Check the answer now. It aligns with your question... `:)`

Comment: children() ignores textnodes and comment nodes, which `contents()` will get.  This will check for the lack of non text nodes, which seems to be what the OP is asking for

Comment: <div>...</div> is not empty, yet it has dots and i would like to remove it. Check my updated question as it might clear things our

Comment: @rob.m So, basically, a div that has any text alone, shouldn't be removed. Got it.

Comment: @rob.m Works now.. Kindly check the answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks a lot, your function bit as per the other answer was correct

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace all strings of `div` element using regular expression `$("div").replace(/\+/g, "");`
2. If replaced element equals to "" (is empty), remove it.

   ```
   if($("div").replace(/\+/g, "") == "") {
     $("div").remove();
   }
   ```

Comment: <div>...</div> is not empty

Comment: the div isn't empty it has characters like the dots and "

Comment: **1.** You didn't follow the Stack Overflow answering pattern. **2.** And still your answer is wrong. But anyway, I corrected it.

Comment: Man, don't you know how to post the answer? Seriously? If you don't know, please learn!